# Getting com.android.volley.ServerError

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-volley

PUT request using volley

```
Log.i("JsonObject is",finaljsonData.toString());
Output:-

{"stats":[{"med_id":1,"med_name":"Evening","start_date":1476107306168,"end_date":1476193706168,"adherence":{"taken_on":[1476107704867],"missed_on":[]}}]}
```

Code:

```
    JsonObjectHeader customRequest=new JsonObjectHeader(Request.Method.PUT,url, finaljsonData, listener, errorListener);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(customRequest);
```

And the JsonObjectHeader class is:-

```
public class JsonObjectHeader extends JsonRequest<JSONObject> {

    public JsonObjectHeader(int method, String url, String requestBody, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, requestBody, listener, errorListener);
    }

    public JsonObjectHeader(String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                            Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        this(jsonRequest == null ? Method.GET : Method.POST, url, jsonRequest,
                listener, errorListener);
    }

    public JsonObjectHeader(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                            Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

        try {
            Log.i("Response parse","Yes");
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            Log.i("Json String",jsonString);
            Log.i("Response Complete",response.toString());
            Log.i("Response Data",response.data.toString());
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        headers.put("x-access-token", Constants.getTokenDB());
        return headers;

    }

}
```

LogCat OutPut:

```
10-10 19:45:15.186 22355-22426/user.com.test2 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f5ba7cac7e0
10-10 19:45:15.797 22355-22650/user.com.test2 E/Volley: [198] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for url
10-10 19:45:15.798 22355-22355/user.com.test2 W/System.err: com.android.volley.ServerError
10-10 19:45:15.798 22355-22355/user.com.test2 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:163)
10-10 19:45:15.798 22355-22355/user.com.test2 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Server LogCat:-

```
{}
www-user-9 PUT /medstats 500 4.579 ms - 627

 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
www-user-9     at /abc.js:390:12
www-user-9     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/xyz.js.js:95:5)
www-user-9     at next (/abc.js:131:13)
www-user-9     at /abc.js:61:5
www-user-9     at //abc.js:27:18
www-user-9     at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
www-user-9     at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:390:13)
```

I have tried using PostMan. So it is working fine: so I think no server error

Comment: You have a server error (ie outside your app). You will need to check the server logs for the root cause of the error then go from there. If you are looking to handle the error on Android you will need to check the status returned by the server.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell I have added server log

Comment: I am getting empty body on server, so this might me error from app

Comment: HTTP.500 us a response code your server gives, not something generated by Volley

Comment: Looks like your server is encountering a null. Are you sending all the values to your server that it requires?

Comment: Server is sending error because it is receiving the null value. @ChrisStillwell.. and yes I am sending all the required values.

Comment: You have access to the server? Then check the `abc.js` file.

Comment: I checked the abc.js file. No error in abc.js error and I also check from Postman with same data.

Answer (score 0):

The json body you are sending as string, try to send it as a json object. The server might be expecting a json object. Else there can be issue with the headers values. Check in postman whether the header that you are sending from there is same as what you are sending from the app.

Comment: I am also sending the jsonObject. this was the typo error.  I checked with the postman, work fine with the same token.